# How to create a hierarchical tree in SQL with two kinds of nodes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have the next table `tree`:

```
 id, name, boss, group
 1, Boss 1, 9, false
 2, Boss 2, 9, false
 3, Group 1, 1, true
 4, Group 2, 2, true
 5, Employee 1, 3, false
 6, Employee 2, 3, false
 7, Employee 3, 3, false
 8, Employee 4, 4, false
 9, Boss 0, null, false
```

Which must be represented in the next way:

```
Boss 0 
|___  Boss 1 
|    |-- Group 1
|    |________ Employee 1
|    |________ Employee 2
|    |________ Employee 3
|___ Boss 2
     |-- Group 2
     |________ Employee 4
```

I can get this result:

```
id, name, level 
9, Boss 0, 1
1, Boss 1, 2
2, Boss 2, 2
3, Group 1, 3
4, Group 2, 3
5, Employee 1, 4
6, Employee 2, 4
7, Employee 3, 4
8, Employee 4, 4
```

using the next query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(id, name, boss, level, group) AS
(
 SELECT
     p1.id,
     p1.name,
     p1.boss,
     1 as level,
     p1.group
     FROM tree as p1
     WHERE p1.boss is null
 UNION ALL
 SELECT p2.id,
     p2.name,
     p2.boss,
     CASE WHEN p2.group = true THEN level + 1
         WHEN p2.group is null THEN level
     END,
     p2.group
 FROM tree as p2
     INNER JOIN t on p2.boss = t.id
 )
 SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.group is null
```

However, what I need to get is the next information: **how many people are directly and indirectly below under each employee?** For example:

```
Boss 0:
   2 Direct
   4 Indirect
```

That is, what I am looking for is something like this:

```
id, name, level 
9, Boss 0, 1
1, Boss 1, 2
2, Boss 2, 2
3, Group 1, 3
4, Group 2, 3
5, Employee 1, 3
6, Employee 2, 3
7, Employee 3, 3
8, Employee 4, 3
```

What can I do in this case? Do you think is better idea to use the nested set model for this kind of problem?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres?

Comment: Yes @a_horse_with_no_name , I am using Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify RDBMS so I use SQL Server:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a53e1/29/0)**

```
WITH t(id, name, boss, [level], [group]) AS
(
  SELECT
     p1.id,
     p1.name,
     p1.boss,
     1 as [level],
     p1.[group]
   FROM tree as p1
   WHERE p1.boss IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
     p2.id,
     p2.name,
     p2.boss,
     CASE WHEN t.[group] = 0 THEN [level] + 1
         ELSE [level]
     END,
     p2.[group]
   FROM tree as p2
   JOIN t 
     ON p2.boss = t.id
 )
SELECT * 
FROM t
```

Comment: The `recursive` keyword in the example (required the SQL standard) suggests either Postgres or Firebird

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I wish I knew them better. SQL Server mostly :)

Comment: Yes, I am using Postgres

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense the condition in the `case`; when `group` is false the level remains with no changes.